# Embed iframe Amazon Associate Link into .md file R

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I'm trying to embed a link into a post created using R blogdown and Hugo. It is a simple .md file.

The code I am trying to post is this:

```
<iframe src="//example.com/foo/bar"></iframe>
```

I see nothing where the content is supposed to appear.

Since it's a .md file, I thought it would simply take the HTML tag and work. Apparently, that's not my case.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Hugo v0.60.0+ and want to use raw HTML in your `.md` file, include the following in your config.yaml.

```yaml
markup:
  goldmark:
    renderer:
      unsafe: true
```

With this “unsafe” setting, Hugo will pass raw HTML — for example <br> — through to the destination file.

This is an excerpt of section [14.2 markup](https://www.ii.com/themeless-gitless-intro-hugo/#_markup) in my Hugo Tutorial. For more about this, see [Configure Markup](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup/) in the Hugo Docs.

Comment: This worked perfectly after I converted from a toml file to a yaml file. I failed to mention I was using config.toml file. Tested this out and it works now.